# Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’

Tags: r

I am trying to install `tidyverse` package in order to use gather function in my script. I am getting the following message every time I try to install the package:

```
* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/nasser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/nasser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lxml2
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libxml-2.0 was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libxml2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libxml2-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libxml2_dev (Solaris)
If libxml-2.0 is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libxml-2.0.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘xml2’
* removing ‘/home/nasser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/xml2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/nasser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘xml2’, ‘httr’ are not available for package ‘rvest’
* removing ‘/home/nasser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rvest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘rvest’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/nasser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpAkUxg4/downloaded_packages’
```

I have no idea what all that means and I could not solve it. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome the 57+-package-dependency-with-compolation lollapalooza that is the tidyverse on Linux. See if this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719942/how-to-install-tidyverse-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-17-04 helps. Also, look at the `Dockerfile`s in https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned and you'll see all the `apt-get`s that it uses to prep a linux Docker container for R work, including the `tidyverse`

Answer (score 4):

I'd put this in a comment as well but it doesn't work in that format. I'm kinda hoping the actual comment has the solution so this question can be marked as a duplicate.

The output actually did give instructions, but it's all smushed together and somewhat foreboding (which is somewhat appropriate given the proximity to Halloween).

```
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
```

says you need to know which linux distribution you have and install the `libcurl` OS package for it before trying to install the tidyverse.

```
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libxml-2.0 was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libxml2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libxml2-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libxml2_dev (Solaris)
If libxml-2.0 is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libxml-2.0.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

says you need to know which linux distribution you have and install the `libxml2` OS package for it before trying to install the tidyverse.

While you're at it, make sure you have the `openssl` OS package installed as well.